# Formatting date with TEXT function when using excel in different language

Tags: excel, excel-formula

This has been a headache for a long time. I have some dates in an excel column which I want to format as `=TEXT(A2, "yymmdd")`. Imagine column A is where I have the dates listed.
If the date was **19/03/2020**, it formats it correctly for me as **200319**, since my excel is in English.
But when I send it to a colleague that has his excel in Spanish he sees **yy0319**. This is because to have the formula to work in Spanish you need `=TEXT(A2, "aammdd")`.

Do you know any way of solving this issue while keeping using the TEXT function? I managed to find kind of a turnaround with `=RIGHT(YEAR(B2),2)&TEXT(MONTH(B2),"mm")&TEXT(DAY(B2),"dd")`, but it looks messier.

Thank you!

Comment: to you want to keep using the text function, or is it ok just to have the result as text?

Comment: If possible, keep using the TEXT function. But thank you fo the alternative provided, I did not think about that.

Answer (score 1):

ASSUMING B2 is an excel serial date and not a text date.

```
=RIGHT(YEAR(B2),2)&RIGHT("0"&MONTH(B2),2)&RIGHT("0"&DAY(B2))
```

The `"0"&` provide a leading zero when the result is a single digit.  By taking right 2, it drops the leading zero when the result is 2 digits.  Because the whole thing is slapped together with & the result will be a number stored as text.